# How to colorize `gcal`

Tags: colors, calendar

I'm using `gcal`.
http://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/manual/gcal.html

Is there easy way to make Saturday blue and Sunday red?
If there is another CLI program that provides the same functionality in OSX, I would be willing to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try generic colorizer - [grc and grcat](https://github.com/pengwynn/grc/blob/master/grcat).

[image: grc screenshot]